# VS2017 Angular template - webapi listens on one port, angular client on another

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I just upgraded VS2017 to the latest, 15.8.6, today.  If I go in and create a .NET Core 2.1 project (from within the IDE, not command line), and select the Angular template, and run it without making any other changes, the app doesn't work.

What I've found is that the WebApi portion of the project is listening on port 54401:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:54401/

while the Angular client is listening on port 54420:

> ng serve --extract-css "--port" "54420"
> ** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:54420, open your browser on http://localhost:54420/ **

In previous versions of VS2017, both the client and server were listening on the same port, or, at least, I didn't have to do anything special to get the application to work.

Is this new behavior normal? What do I need to do to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the app doesn't work?"  Nothing spins up?  client and api can't connect?  What does the browser console/dev tools say when you run it?  Anytime you are running between different ports, you will run into CORS issues and need to configure CORS in the API project to allow calls from the client.

Comment: when running from within Visual Studio, the browser starts on port 54401, but, since that's the port of the WebApi, nothing happens.  If I change the port in the browser to 54420, my application loads, but all of the calls to WebApi now fail

Comment: Do you have CORS enabled and configured in your API project?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I enabled CORS but still have the problem, The problem is the client is making calls to a url/port that isn't listening.  The Web API is on another port, so the calls from the client never get through

Comment: Why can't you change the client to call the correct port?

Comment: I would still have the problem that the browser starts on the Web API port, not the port the client is listening on.  How can I change the project so both start on the same port?  Why has this even changed in VS?  Is there a benefit?

Comment: You can change the startup url in your project settings.

Comment: The angular client never starts on the same port twice.  I've tried a few different ways to force a port, but nothing works.  Any suggestions?